# Issue targeting last-of-type varying children using css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to target the last paragraph in the entire article. Other contents may vary, the following is an example. What is the appropriate selector. article p:last-child nor article p:last-of-type works.

```
article
 div.container
  div.row
   div.col-12
    p
    p
 div.container
  div.row
   div.col-12
    p
    p
    div.row
     div.col-12
      p
      p
    p
    p <-- trying to target this paragraph
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of variations in the DOM structure, and which of the paragraphs you want matched in those examples? Selectors are very sensitive to element structure and you may not be able to write a selector covering all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can select last paragraph using below:

```
div.row > div.col-12 > p:last-child{

}
```

Comment: This targets the first, second and fourth time of parargraphs.

Answer (score 0):

If that `div.container` is the last element of article, then this would help you.

```
div.container:last-child > div.row:first-child > div.col-12 > p:last-child{
    
}
```